# Why image sliding not display consecutive?

Tags: android, slider

```
HashMap<String,Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        file_maps.put("M/S 1",R.drawable.rs1);
        file_maps.put("M/S 2",R.drawable.rs2);
        file_maps.put("M/S 3",R.drawable.rs3);
        file_maps.put("M/S 4",R.drawable.rs4);


        for(String name : file_maps.keySet()){
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(file_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);

mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
```

i use this code , suppose to be the first image appear is rs1 , second rs2 , third rs3 and last rs4 ..

But the problem is image rs3 will first display , second rs4 , third rs1 and last rs2 ..

So how i can solve this problem ? or have any idea why this problem happen ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
  HashMap file_maps = new HashMap();
```

Use

```
  HashMap file_maps = new LinkedHashMap();
```

> > **[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)** makes absolutely no guarantees about the iteration order. It can (and will) even change completely when new elements are added.
> >
> > **[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)** will iterate in the order in which the entries were put into the map

Comment: @JohnShuk Happy to help you. :-)